# intersecting n number of queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, search, select, full-text-search

I am trying to write a search application using mysql and i have the following schema:

```
Table   -->   Fields

word_index --> word_id,word

index_group --> word_id,file_id

file_info --> file_id,file_name
```

Imagine a file `foo.txt` containing the word `abc`
So what I basically do if someone searches for the word `"abc"`

```
SELECT file_name FROM file_info WHERE  file_id IN 
(SELECT file_id FROM index_group WHERE word_id IN 
(SELECT word_id FROM word_index WHERE word='abc'))
```

which displays `foo.txt`

Now when I search for multiple words across multiple files what approach do I take. One thing I can do is split the query and apply `INTERSECT` on all the n results. But MySQL does not support `INTERSECT`. What should be my approach?

EDIT

I will attach an example from wiki to demonstrate what I want

```
T[0] = "it is what it is"
T[1] = "what is it"
T[2] = "it is a banana"
```

we have the following inverted file index (where the integers in the set notation brackets refer to the indexes (or keys) of the text symbols, T[0], T[1] etc.):

```
"a":      {2}
"banana": {2}
"is":     {0, 1, 2}
"it":     {0, 1, 2}
"what":   {0, 1}
```

A term search for the terms "what", "is" and "it" would give the set {0,1} intersect {0,1,2} intersect {0,1,2} = {0,1}.

However in future I might have to do TF-IDF for cases when 2 out of 3 words appear together. SO I want to abstract the 3 results and then intersect them.

Comment: `WHERE word IN('abc','cdg')`?

Comment: this works when both the words would be in the same file. what about the other case? I will attach an example from wiki

Comment: No, Sarkar, this wouldn't work when both words in the same file and otherwise not. Arion was simply mistaken; you would get all files containing at least one of the words. A union instead of an intersection, so to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to get only those files that contain *all* requested words. To achieve this, select all files containing one or more of those words and then count how many matches you got. If you look for three words and find a file with three different matches, then you found all words.

```
SELECT file_name 
FROM file_info 
WHERE  file_id IN 
(
  SELECT file_id 
  FROM index_group 
  WHERE word_id IN 
  (
    SELECT word_id 
    FROM word_index 
    WHERE word IN ('abc','def','ghi')
  )
  GROUP BY file_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT word_id) = 3 -- all three words
);
```

Comment: How is my answer different from what you are asking? You are looking for "what", "is" and "it", get three matching files, but as only two contain all words, the having clause removes one file. Isn't this what you are asking and what my query does? And if in future two words suffice, then change the HAVING clause to `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT word_id) >= 2`.